# c++ comparing sum of arrays

Tags: c++, algorithm

i have 2 arrays each with 5  integers, how can i compare both of array so that array A is larger than array B, following are my code where i get return 0:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    const int AMAX = 5, BMAX = 6;
    int i;
    bool c1 = true, c2 = false;
    int A[AMAX] = { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 };
    int B[BMAX] = { 6, 7,8, 9, 1};

    for (i = 0; i < BMAX; i++)
        if (B[i] == A[i])       
            cout << c1 << endl;
        else
            cout << c2 << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

What am i missing here?

update:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int main(){
  int a[] = {6,7,29};
  int b[] = {3,2,11};
  int acc1=0;
  int acc2 = 0;
  for (int i=0;i<3;i++){
    acc1+=a[i];
}
  for(int j=0;j<3;j++){
    acc2+=b[j];
}

if(acc1 < acc2){
  printf("Array B is greater than Array B ");
}

else{
  printf("Array B greater than Array A");
}

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "array A is larger than array B"?

Comment: Where do you want to compare the cell in the bigger array, that has no counterpart in the smaller one?

Comment: The code has undefined behaviour as it is accessing beyond the bounds of array `A`.

Comment: "What am i missing here?" --- A good chunk of Programming 101

Comment: The title says "comparing sum of arrays". Where's the sum?

Comment: sum of array A larger than sum of array B. I think this is what the question mean

Comment: Tell me is these two arrays equal: `{1,2,3,4}` and `{1,2,3}` in your definitions?

Comment: @NPE comapring which sum of array is larger.

Comment: @MM. comparing sum of each array whether sum of A is greater than sum of B or vice versa

Comment: This question does not make the slightest sense. Do you know what the word "sum" means?

Answer (score 1):

You can use built-in algorithm `std::equal` to compare two arrays. Example:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>
using namespace std;
#define countof(x) sizeof(x)/sizeof(x[0])
int main()
{
    int A[] = { 2, 4, 1, 5, 9 };
    int B[] = { 9, 12, 32, 43, 23};
    int C[] = { 2, 4, 1, 5, 9 };
    cout << equal(A, A + countof(A), B) << endl;
    cout << equal(A, A + countof(A), C) << endl;
}
```

Output: `0 1`

Comment: no seems not works as wanted

Answer (score 1):

If what you want to compare are the *sums* of the elements in the array (i.e. determine whether the sum of all elements in `A` is greater than the sum of all elements in `B`), as the question's title seems to imply, this should do what you want:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>
#include <numeric>
#include <iomanip>

int main()
{
    using namespace std;

    int A[] = { 2, 4, 1, 5, 9 };
    int B[] = { 9, 12, 32, 43, 23};

    int sumA = accumulate(begin(A), end(A), 0);
    int sumB = accumulate(begin(B), end(B), 0);

    cout << boolalpha << (sumA > sumB);

    return 0;
}
```

In case you are not using C++11, here is the equivalent program written in C++03:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <numeric>

int main()
{
    using namespace std;

    int A[] = { 2, 4, 1, 5, 9 };
    int B[] = { 9, 12, 32, 43, 23};

    int sumA = accumulate(A, A + sizeof(A) / sizeof(int), 0);
    int sumB = accumulate(B, B + sizeof(B) / sizeof(int), 0);

    cout << ((sumA > sumB) ? "true" : "false");

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: test.cpp: In function ‘int main()’:
test.cpp:11:34: error: ‘begin’ was not declared in this scope
test.cpp:11:42: error: ‘end’ was not declared in this scope
test.cpp:11:46: error: ‘accumulate’ was not declared in this scope

Comment: @SaraswathiApavoo: Are you using C++11?

Comment: @SaraswathiApavoo: Try the second version in my updated answer.

Comment: this is what i using g++ test.cpp -o test

Comment: both your code still shows up error in my CLI

Comment: @SaraswathiApavoo: What's CLI?

Comment: @SaraswathiApavoo: You can see my code working [here](http://liveworkspace.org/code/3COedR$7)

Comment: Before C++11 it should look like this: http://liveworkspace.org/code/2IpzkV$3 . `std::accumulate()` is in `<numeric>`.

Comment: @Johnsyweb: Thank you, I didn't know `accumulate` was defined in `<numeric>`.

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
int suma;
int sumb;

int A[] = { 2, 4, 1, 5, 9 };
int B[] = { 9, 12, 32, 43, 23};

suma = accumulate(A, A + sizeof(A) / sizeof(int), 0);
sumb = accumulate(B, B + sizeof(B) / sizeof(int), 0);

cout << ((sumA > sumB) ? "true" : "false");

return 0;
}
```