# c++ passing function into main error

Tags: c++

hi i have following c++ code where i want call function into main, following are my code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <numeric>

int main()
{

    using namespace std;

    readData();

    int sumA = accumulate(A, A + sizeof(A) / sizeof(int), 0);
    int sumB = accumulate(B, B + sizeof(B) / sizeof(int), 0);

    cout << ((sumA > sumB) ? "Array A Greater Than Array B\n" : "Array B Greater Than Array A\n");


    return 0;
}

void readData()
{

int A[] = { 1, 1, 8};
int B[] = { 2, 2, 2};
}
```

I have following error on cli :

```
test.cpp:3:7: error: storage size of ‘B’ isn’t known
test.cpp:4:7: error: storage size of ‘A’ isn’t known
```

Where am i wrong here? Thanks

Comment: '`cout << ((sumA > sumB) ? "Array A Greater Than Array B\n" : "Array B Greater Than Array A\n");`'? What about the case where `sumA == sumB`?

Comment: how can i compare sums of elements in array..? for above situation how can we writte in better way

Comment: Complete lack of understanding of how language works. Get a good book.

Comment: Your compiler should emit some more useful errors (such as those here: http://liveworkspace.org/code/2g3oE0$0) but I'd expect anyone with a modicum of [tag:c++] experience to be able to work it out from the errors you gave there. `A` and `B` are not declared in `main()` and therefore cannot be used in that context. You need to rewrite this code to make more sense in your chosen programming language.

Answer (score 6):

The variables `A` and `B` are local to the function `readData` and not accessible from any other function.

Either declare them as global variables (not recommended) or as local variables in `main` and pass them as arguments to the `readData` function.

I also recommend you use [`std::vector`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector) instead of plain arrays.

Comment: The use of plain arrays will make more sense if you read this: http://stackoverflow.com/a/15197954/78845

Comment: how to write it more better..? any ideas

Answer (score 0):

First of all, be careful with taking the size of arrays in C and C++. Read here for more information: http://www.cplusplus.com/faq/sequences/arrays/sizeof-array/

However do use std::vector instead like this.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <numeric>

typedef std::vector<int> int_vec_t;

//Call by reference to set variables in function
void readData(int_vec_t& v1, int_vec_t& v2)
{
  v1 = int_vec_t{1,1,8}; //This only works for C++11
  v2 = int_vec_t{2,2,2};
}

void readUserData(int_vec_t& v)
{
  for(;;)
  {
    int val;
    std::cin>>val;
    if(val == 0) break;
    v.push_back(val);
  }
}

int main()
{
    using namespace std;

    int_vec_t A;
    int_vec_t B;

    readData(A,B);
    //Or
    readUserData(A);
    readUserData(B);

    int sumA = accumulate(A.begin(), A.end(), 0); //Then use iterators
    int sumB = accumulate(B.begin(), B.end(), 0);

    cout << ((sumA > sumB) ? "Array A Greater Than Array B\n" : "Array B Greater Than Array A\n");

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: how to pass user input to both of array then?lets says we want to pass 5 elements into each array..

Comment: something in the line of the `readUserData` function I just added. However handling user input is a tricky matter which is outside the scope of this answer.

Comment: where is readUserData..?

Comment: @AxelOmega not working, got errors..