# C++ reading user inputs comparing array

Tags: c++, arrays, c++11

I have this code where it read user code and store it on array, and later find sums of elements on each array and compare both of them, the code is as follows:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <numeric>

typedef std::vector<int> int_vec_t;

//Call by reference to set variables in function
void readData(int_vec_t& v1, int_vec_t& v2)
{
  v1 = int_vec_t{1,1,8}; //This only works for C++11
  v2 = int_vec_t{2,2,2};
}

void readUserData(int_vec_t& v)
{
  for(;;)
  {
    int val;
    std::cin>>val;
    if(val == 0) break;
    v.push_back(val);
  }
}

int main()
{
    using namespace std;

    int_vec_t A;
    int_vec_t B;

    readData(A,B);
    //Or
    readUserData(A);
    readUserData(B);

    int sumA = accumulate(A.begin(), A.end(), 0); //Then use iterators
    int sumB = accumulate(B.begin(), B.end(), 0);

    cout << ((sumA > sumB) ? "Array A Greater Than Array B\n" : "Array B Greater Than Array A\n");

    return 0;
}
```

But the above code generate following errors:

```
test.cpp: In function ‘void readData(int_vec_t&, int_vec_t&)’:
```

I am using `g++ test.cpp -o test` to compile the code. What am I missing here?

Comment: That's not the error. It's saying the error is in that function. You should be able to just say `v1 = {1,1,8};`, by the way.

Comment: @chris then how can i modified readData(int_vec_t& v1, int_vec_t& v2) and readUserData(int_vec_t& v) functions?

Comment: Your code compiles fine [here](http://liveworkspace.org/code/SWmBI$1)

Comment: @AndyProwl how can i set so each array only can accept 5 elements?

Comment: @SaraswathiApavoo: Is this the question you meant to ask? Because there is no trace of it in the text of your question

Comment: @AndyProwl since it keeps taking inputs, it would be better if i can limit to 5

Comment: [@AxelOmega's code](http://stackoverflow.com/a/15225669/78845) compiles and runs as specified [here](http://liveworkspace.org/code/24Jxv0$1). Please follow the suggestions to read [a good C++ book](http://stackoverflow.com/q/388242/78845). Your questions are all due to fundamental misunderstandings as to how [tag:c++] works and StackOverflow cannot teach you to program in any language. Sorry.

Answer (score 3):

don't you think the compilation should be something like:

`$ g++ -std=c++11 test.cpp -o test` ?

> it keep taking inputs, how can i limit it to take only 5 elements per array

```
void readUserData(int_vec_t& v)
{
  for(int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
  {
    int val;
    std::cin>>val;
   // if(val == 0) return;
    v.push_back(val);
  }
}
```

> Great thanks, in between the loop how can out put statement so that user knows he is entering array for array 1 and after that array 2?

```
void readUserData(int_vec_t& v, std::string default = "")
{
  for(int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
  {
    int val;
    std::cout << "Enter for "<< default << "[" << i << "]: ";
    std::cin>>val;
   // if(val == 0) return;
    v.push_back(val);
  }
}
```

And from your `main()` you can send in a different string.

for example like this:

```
readUserData(A, "A");
readUserData(B, "B");
```

Comment: ok works fine but still it takes user input but not printing anything

Comment: @SaraswathiApavoo what do you mean it is not printing anything? It has to either print one of those two strings

Comment: it keep taking inputs, how can i limit it to take only 5 elements per array

Comment: Great thanks, in between the loop how can out put statement so that user knows he is entering array for array 1 and after that array 2?

Comment: nope, i means like this, Please enter value for array A -- once done input 5 elements, it will ask again Please enter values for array B..

Comment: Yours works fine but it keep print index Enter for [i]. Thanks

Comment: got errors: test.cpp:14:45: error: expected ‘,’ or ‘...’ before ‘default’
test.cpp: In function ‘void readUserData(int_vec_t&, std::string)’:
test.cpp:19:33: error: expected primary-expression before ‘default’
test.cpp:19:33: error: expected ‘;’ before ‘default’

Answer (score 2):

This was my code posted as a suggested solution to
[c++ passing function into main error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15225040/c-passing-function-into-main-error/15225669#15225669)

Yes it needs a C++11 compiler as stated in the code. It was never meant as final code either.

I would recommend the OP to read a good book about C++. Let me suggest "C++ The Programming Language" [http://www.amazon.com/The-Programming-Language-3rd-Edition/dp/0201889544](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0201889544)